# First time protege user, trying to export a simple ontology to AWS dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, protege

I am currently using protege 5.0 and have created a very simple ontology (the pizza example).  I was wondering how I would export this ontology to dynamodb on AWS.  I was hoping someone could post a link to a good tutorial on protege 5.0 or walk me through this.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you done some research ? You should give a try at least to make a first draft which could help us to guide you through a solution.

Comment: I've done some research, and made a basic ontology in Protege.  I was following this video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9ERlUgvgwM&list=PLea0WJq13cnAfCC0azrCyquCN_tPelJN1 .  In his video he uploads it to his personal server.  Is it really as easy as just uploading it to my AWS database using something like filezilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using dynamodb just to store the content of a file and to be able to access the file at a specific URL, then the process required is just the same as for any other file type you would store on dynamodb. The default way for Protege and most other OWL related tools to access an ontology is a simple HTTP get from a provided IRI.